# Iptables / Ip6tables - a few questions

Tags: security, iptables, firewall

So, i was working on my iptables.

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.test.rules

iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP 

## On drop les scans XMAS et NULL.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,URG,PSH FIN,URG,PSH -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP

# Dropper silencieusement tous les paquets broadcastés.
iptables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j DROP

# Droping all invalid packets
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

# Autorise les connexions déjà établies et localhost                
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT        
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT   
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT


#TOR
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9050 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# ICMP (Ping)                                       
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP                       
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j DROP

# DNS                                           
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT                 
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT                     

# HTTP                                          
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# HTTPS
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT                    

# Mail SMTP 
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT  

#Transmission
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 51413 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 51413 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# NTP (horloge du serveur) 
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT    

# On log les paquets en entrée.
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG

# On log les paquets en sortie.
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG

# On log les paquets forward.
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG 


ip6tables -F
ip6tables -X
ip6tables -t nat -F
ip6tables -t nat -X
ip6tables -t mangle -F
ip6tables -t mangle -X
ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP 

## On drop les scans XMAS et NULL.
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,URG,PSH FIN,URG,PSH -j DROP
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP

# Dropper silencieusement tous les paquets broadcastés.
ip6tables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j DROP

# Droping all invalid packets
ip6tables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
ip6tables -A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

# Autorise les connexions déjà établies et localhost                
ip6tables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT       
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
ip6tables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT


#ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 -j DROP
#ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 -j DROP
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type router-advertisement -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
#ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type router-solicitation -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type neighbour-advertisement -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type neighbour-solicitation -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
#ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type router-advertisement -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type router-solicitation -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type neighbour-advertisement -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type neighbour-solicitation -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 -j DROP
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 -j DROP

#TOR
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9050 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# DNS                                           
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT                 
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT                     

# HTTP                                          
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT                

# HTTPS
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT                   

# Mail SMTP 
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

#Transmission
ip6tables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 51413 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 51413 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# NTP (horloge du serveur) 
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT   

# On log les paquets en entrée.
ip6tables -A INPUT -j LOG

# On log les paquets en sortie.
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j LOG

# On log les paquets forward.
ip6tables -A FORWARD -j LOG 


exit 0
```

I have three questions :

First, do you see any ameliorations, anything i could have forgotten to make my firewall more secure ?

Second, how to apply the rules at boot before connection to internet using network-manager ? Some said to me that placing the script in /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables wasn't secure.

And last, any software besides iptables, ip6tables and fail2ban that could be useful ?

Thanks in advance !

NB : sorry, english isn't my first langage.